# Ecg graph with html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, graph, html5-canvas

My need is to draw a ECG graph on canvas for socket data per every data iteration.

[image]

I tried to look into several graph plugins which use canvas to plot graphs, tried http://www.flotcharts.org/ but didn't succeed.

I Tried to plot graph using below basic html5 canvas drawline with sample data.

```
var fps = 60;
var n = 1;

drawWave();
    function drawWave() {
        setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(drawWave2);
                ctx.lineWidth = "2";
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
                // Drawing code goes here
                n += 1;
                if (n >= data.length) {
                    n = 1;
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1] * 2);
                ctx.lineTo(n, data[n] * 2);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.clearRect(n + 1, 0, 10, canvas.height);
            }, 1000 / fps);
    }
```

But it is not giving me the exact graph view as attached image. I'm not able to understand how to achieve graph like ecg graph. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characteristics with an ECG is that is plots the signal horizontally headed by a blank gap. When the end of the right side is reached is returns to left side and overdraw the existing graph.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/tFn66/)

[image: ECG]

**Setup**

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,

    /// plot x and y, old plot x and y, speed and scan bar width
    speed = 3,
    px = 0, opx = 0, 
    py = h * 0.8, opy = py,
    scanBarWidth = 20;

ctx.strokeStyle = '#00bd00';
ctx.lineWidth = 3;

/// for demo we use mouse as signal input source    
demo.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var r = demo.getBoundingClientRect();
    py = e.clientY - r.top;
}
loop();
```

**The main loop:**

The loop will plot whatever the signal amplitude is at any moment. You can inject a sinus or some other signal or read from an actual sensor over Web socket etc.

```
function loop() {

    /// move forward at defined speed
    px += speed;
    
    /// clear ahead (scan bar)
    ctx.clearRect(px,0, scanBarWidth, h);

    /// draw line from old plot point to new
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(opx, opy);
    ctx.lineTo(px, py);
    ctx.stroke();
    
    /// update old plot point
    opx = px;
    opy = py;
    
    /// check if edge is reached and reset position
    if (opx > w) {
        px = opx = -speed;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

To inject a value simply update `py` (outside loop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I tried with this http://jsfiddle.net/atluriajith/e7z5D/1/ but if input array is serial numbers with minute difference (this exact data coming from my socket) then the graph which is plotting over is looking like straight line. How can we plot with that values to get require graph.

Comment: @atluriajith To monitor minute lengths just reduce the speed to a very small value. To get one window represent M minute(s) you can calculate: `speed = width / (60 x 60 x M)`

Comment: @atluriajith Example: [30 sec window](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/tFn66/2/)

Comment: With speed it is just getting slow to plot, but my requirement is graph needs to be adjust its dimensions and for every values graph should be like http://i.stack.imgur.com/s6euF.png

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Problem solved with your code. http://jsfiddle.net/atluriajith/e7z5D/3/

Answer (score 1):

It would be far more helpful, if you included an image of what it *does* produce, rather than stating that it doesn't do that. Anyhow, it looks like you're only drawing a single line per frame. You need to run a loop with lineTo inside, iterating through all values of n.

Something along the lines of the below except from a sound-synthesizer. Just pay attention to the fact that there's a drawing-loop. In my case, there are often 40,000 or 50,000 samples that need to be drawn on a canvas of only a few hundred pixels wide. It seems like redundant drawing in my case, but doing th intuitive thing, of a single point per pixel results in an inaccurate image. The output of this looks something (88200 samples per 1024 pixels)

[image]

```
function drawFloatArray(samples, canvas)
{
    var i, n = samples.length;
    var dur = (n / 44100 * 1000)>>0;
    canvas.title = 'Duration: ' +  dur / 1000.0 + 's';

    var width=canvas.width,height=canvas.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.moveTo(0,height/2);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = (i*width) / n;
        y = (samples[i]*height/2)+height/2;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your live data is streaming non-stop, you need a plan to deal with a graph that overflows the canvas.

Here's one solution that pans the canvas to always show only the most recent data.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f5sT4/

Here's starting code illustrating this solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // capture incoming socket data in an array
    var data=[];

    // TESTING: fill data with some test values
    for(var i=0;i<5000;i++){
        data.push(Math.sin(i/10)*70+100);
    }

    // x is your most recent data-point in data[]
    var x=0;

    // panAtX is how far the plot will go rightward on the canvas
    // until the canvas is panned

    var panAtX=250;

    var continueAnimation=true;
    animate();


    function animate(){

        if(x>data.length-1){return;}

        if(continueAnimation){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        if(x++<panAtX){

            ctx.fillRect(x,data[x],1,1);

        }else{

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            // plot data[] from x-PanAtX to x 

            for(var xx=0;xx<panAtX;xx++){
                var y=data[x-panAtX+xx];
                ctx.fillRect(xx,y,1,1)
            }
        }
    }


    $("#stop").click(function(){continueAnimation=false;});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent) web component is both prettier and easier to use. It using canvas as a backend of draw. If you going use it all you need to do is call `bang()` on every appearing beat

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<ecg-line></ecg-line>';
ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
```

[image]

Comment: This library seems pretty new, I was able to make it work with the pure Javascript and request animation frame. But this new library will help others,Thanks for sharing this :) .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("dm_graphs");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ls = 0;
d = 7; // sesitivity

function updateFancyGraphs() {

  var gh = canvas.height;
  var gh2 = gh / 2;
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, -1, 0);
  ctx.fillRect(graphX, 0, 1, canvas.height);
  var size = Math.max(-gh, Math.min((3 * (Math.random() * 10 - 5)) * d, gh));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(graphX - 1, gh2 + ls / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(graphX, gh2 + size / 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ls = size;
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.offsetWidth;
  canvas.width = w / 1.5;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 1.5;
  graphX = canvas.width - 1;
  ctx.lineWidth = 1; // 1.75 is nicer looking but loses a lot of information.
  ctx.strokeStyle = "Lime";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
resizeCanvas();

z = setInterval(() => updateFancyGraphs(), 20)
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100ev;
}

body,
html,
canvas {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  height: 100hv;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #113355;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dm_status,
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

#dm_graphs {
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Zibri's Graph</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="dm_graphs"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```